# Why do I get execution failed for task ':app:buildNdkBuildDebug[armeabi-v7a]' when I run whisper project in real mobile phone?

Tags: android

I'm able to run the project https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp/tree/master/examples/whisper.android on Android Studio emulator  (Pixel XL API 13, you can see the Image A)  without any issues.

But I get the following error when I run the project in real mobile phone, I get the following error, why?

```
Execution failed for task ':app:buildNdkBuildDebug[armeabi-v7a]'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: make: Nothing to be done for 'whisper'.
  [armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : whisper_vfpv4 <= ggml.c

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:buildNdkBuildDebug[armeabi-v7a]'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    ...
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: make: Nothing to be done for 'whisper'.
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : whisper_vfpv4 <= ggml.c

C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
    @echo off
    "C:\\Android_SDK\\ndk\\25.1.8937393\\ndk-build.cmd" ^
      "NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null" ^
      "APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=E:\\Android_Studio_Sample\\Whisper\\examples\\whisper.android\\app\\src\\main\\jni\\whisper\\Android.mk" ^
      "NDK_APPLICATION_MK=E:\\Android_Studio_Sample\\Whisper\\examples\\whisper.android\\app\\src\\main\\jni\\whisper\\Application.mk" ^
      "APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a" ^
      "NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a" ^
      "NDK_DEBUG=1" ^
      "APP_PLATFORM=android-26" ^
      "NDK_OUT=E:\\Android_Studio_Sample\\Whisper\\examples\\whisper.android\\app\\build\\intermediates\\cxx\\Debug\\11u1e1z2/obj" ^
      "NDK_LIBS_OUT=E:\\Android_Studio_Sample\\Whisper\\examples\\whisper.android\\app\\build\\intermediates\\cxx\\Debug\\11u1e1z2/lib" ^
      whisper ^
      whisper_vfpv4
  from E:\Android_Studio_Sample\Whisper\examples\whisper.android\app
error: unable to open output file 'E:\Android_Studio_Sample\Whisper\examples\whisper.android\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\11u1e1z2/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/whisper_vfpv4/E_/Android_Studio_Sample/Whisper/examples/whisper.android/app/src/main/jni/whisper/__/__/__/__/__/__/__//ggml.o': 'No such file or directory'
1 error generated.
make: *** [C:/Android_SDK/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/../build/core/build-binary.mk:422: E:\Android_Studio_Sample\Whisper\examples\whisper.android\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\11u1e1z2/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/whisper_vfpv4/E_/Android_Studio_Sample/Whisper/examples/whisper.android/app/src/main/jni/whisper/__/__/__/__/__/__/__//ggml.o] Error 1

    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
```

**Image A**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message shows that there's a problem while building the native C++ code using Android NDK. The build sys says that there's no need to rebuild it, but found an error when compiling for the armeabi-v7a arch.
This may be due to file permissions or path issues. To fix it, you can try to clean the project and rebuild it from scratch. There's a "Build" menu on Android Studio, click on "Clean Project" then try rebuilding the project to see if it works.
You may consider updating Android NDK to the lasted version.